# Use Comment to avoid OpenCL Error on NVIDIA

Tags: opencl

I wrote the following code for my test NVIDIA and AMD GPUs

```
kernel void computeLayerOutput_Rolled(
    global Layer* layers, 
    global float* weights, 
    global float* output,
    constant int* restrict netSpec, 
    int layer)
{
    const int n = get_global_size(0);
    const int nodeNumber = get_global_id(0); //There will be an offset depending on the layer we are operating on

    int numberOfWeights;
    float t;
    //getPosition(i, netSpec, &layer, &nodeNumber);
    numberOfWeights = layers[layer].nodes[nodeNumber].numberOfWeights;

    //if (sizeof(Layer) > 60000)  // This is the extra code add for nvidia
    //      exit(0);

    t = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j != numberOfWeights; ++j)
        t += threeD_access(weights, layer, nodeNumber, j, MAXSIZE, MAXSIZE) *
                    twoD_access(output, layer-1, j, MAXSIZE);

    twoD_access(output, layer, nodeNumber, MAXSIZE) = sigmoid(t);
}
```

At the beginning, I did not add the code that checking the size of Layer, and it works on AMD Kalindi GPU, but crash and report an error code -36 on NVIDIA Tesla C2075.

Since I had rewritten the struct type `Layer` and decreased the size of it a lot before, I decided to check the size of `Layer` to determine whether this struct defined well in kernel code. Then I added this code

```
if (sizeof(Layer) > 60000)
    exit(0);
```

Then it is OK on NVIDIA. However, the strange thing is, when I add `//` before this just as the given code above, it still works. (I believe I do not need to `make clean && make` when I rewrite something in kernel code, but I still did it) Nevertheless, when I roll back to the version not contains this comment, it fails and the error code -36 appears again. It really puzzles me. I think two versions of my code are identical, isn't it?

Comment: Are you **absolutely** sure that it works with the commented code? That can't be right. Please check the generated PTX in both cases.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae -- I just checked it again, and, it **do** works. I checked the git commits and the **only** difference is the comment. The newer commit (with comment) can work and the older (without comment) cannot.

Comment: **Error -36 is invalid command queue**. That means the code is crashing way before the kernel is ever executed. Probably, it does not even compile, since `exit(0)` is not an OpenCL valid function. Kernels do never return, and do never exit, only the work items can exit, and in that case is a return. I strongly suggest that you check every error code, since OpenCL is probably silently failing elsewhere (no seg faults).

Comment: @DarkZeros -- Yes, I found that `exit` means `return` here. I do met a silent seg fault before, that is, there are 2 identical definition of `Layer`, I changed the one for host but forgot that for kernel, then the kernel reached an illegal address when the index of `layers` is greater than 0. But that bug was fixed and it works well without error on another device. There should not be other silent failure, that is why I add this exit thing.

Comment: @DarkZeros -- You are right, I found another bug that leads to the kernel crash, then both devices can work well now. Maybe comment changes the compiler's behavior and then avoid the crashing... I am still not sure.